# Calculate a time according to criteria in R

Tags: r, time

I'm working on a project to calculate player game times.
My problem is that I want to calculate the "TimeOnIce" of the "Player" when their "Start" and "Stop" fit into those of the "Play".

I hope I've been clear enough

```
Data <- data.table(Name = c("Play", "Play", "Play", "Play", "Player", "Player", "Player"), Start = c("00:15:01", "00:15:56", "00:16:29", "00:22:18", "00:14:58", "00:18:04", "00:20:38"), Stop = c("00:15:24", "00:16:04", "00:21:50", "00:23:33", "00:16:25", "00:19:13", "00:21:22"), TimeOnIce = " ")
```

What i expect :

```
NAME          START         STOP        TIMEONICE
PLAY          00:15:01      00:15:24    
PLAY          00:15:56      00:16:04
PLAY          00:16:29      00:21:50
PLAY          00:22:18      00:23:33
PLAYER        00:14:58      00:16:25    00:00:31
PLAYER        00:18:04      00:19:13    00:01:09
PLAYER        00:20:38      00:21:22    00:01:16
```

[Image Representation to better understand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYSSJ.png)
Thanks

Comment: Please provide desired output

Comment: also, a possible error in your sample data?  Player is on from 00:18:04-00:24:12 AND 00:20:38-00:24:53, these periods overlap. Can these overlaps occur?

Comment: Done @Wimpel also this is not a important thing because I have many player in my Data

Comment: I see.. but in your sample data, the same player in on the field twice for a certain period (00:20:38 until 00:24:12) ... So his TimeOnIce over this period is counted twice...

Comment: @Wimpel You're right. I made a mistake copying and pasting the data. I edited it.

Comment: still a small error in the desired output it seems: should the last TIMEONICE not be 44 seconds ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library( data.table )
library( dplyr ) # <---- for using dplyr::if_else, which leaves POSIXct intact (base::ifelse does not!)
```

**sample data**

```
Data <- data.table(Name = c("Play", "Play", "Play", "Play", "Player", "Player", "Player"), 
               Start = as.POSIXct( c("00:15:01", "00:15:56", "00:16:29", "00:22:18", "00:14:58", "00:18:04", "00:20:38"), format = "%H:%M:%S"),
               Stop = as.POSIXct( c("00:15:24", "00:16:04", "00:21:50", "00:23:33", "00:16:25", "00:19:13", "00:21:22"), format = "%H:%M:%S"))
```

**code**

```
#create a data.table with play periods
dt_play <- Data[ Name == "Play", ]
#key it
setkey( dt_play, Start, Stop )

#create a data.frame with player times
dt_players <- Data[ !Name == "Play", ]

#overlap join, then het the revelant periods playd, and sum per player
result <- foverlaps( dt_players, dt_play, type = "any")

#set time from and to, based on the relevant start- end of periods
result[, `:=`(from = if_else( i.Start < Start, Start, i.Start),
              to = if_else( i.Stop > Stop, Stop, i.Stop) )][]
result[, TimeOnIce := as.numeric( to - from )]
```

**output**

```
#summarise per player
result[, list(TimeOnIce = sum(to - from)), by = i.Name]

#    i.Name TimeOnIce
# 1: Player  144 secs

#or get the results per played interval
result[, list(TimeOnIce = sum(TimeOnIce)), by = list(i.Name, i.Start, i.Stop)]

#    i.Name             i.Start              i.Stop TimeOnIce
# 1: Player 2018-10-11 00:14:58 2018-10-11 00:16:25        31
# 2: Player 2018-10-11 00:18:04 2018-10-11 00:19:13        69
# 3: Player 2018-10-11 00:20:38 2018-10-11 00:21:22        44
```

Comment: That's not what I'm looking for. if the time of the "Player" does not fit into the time of the "Play" then I do not count.
For example if the "Play" starts at OO:15:00 and ends at 00:15:30 and my player's at 00:14:00 and ends at 00:15:15 then my player's "TimeOnIce" is 15 seconds